# How to run function in tests?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, typescript, testing

I'm a Java Developer but I want to have some experience also with NodeJS. In Java, when i make a function, then i can run this function in a simple way with using tests like below:

```
    @Autowired
    SomeService service;

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        SomeDto dto = service.getDto(1L);
        log.info("Retrieved: {}", dto.getName());
    }
```

Right now I can run only this one test and check that my method work properly. But how to do this with using NodeJS? For example i have this method:

```
async getData(id: any): Promise<SomeDto> {
   return this.conn.getRepository(Client).findById(id);
}
```

how to run this method in tests like I'm doing it with Java?

PS. I don't want to create unit test and so on, I want only to run my functions with using tests

thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to create unit test /../ I want only to run my functions with using tests"? Either you write your tests, or you don't have any tests.

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs (Or TS) we have lot of test framework, `mocha` is famous test framework

You can use `mocha` for BDD, TDD, ...

See mocha document in https://mochajs.org/

Below link help you to write test in nodejs and i hope helpful for you:

https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-and-complete-guide-to-mocha-testing-d0e0ea09f09d/

---

Tip: If you want use TDD you can use `sinon` package, this package is so good for TDD and fake function